# Git on macOS keeps files after pull

Tags: git, macos

When pulling the newest version from a git repository using `git` on macOS, some files and folders that were deleted in some past commit still remain after the pull. One folder that is not deleted for instance is `node_modules`. If I delete the entire project's folder and then clone it again from the repository, the contents within the folder are as expected.

I would though expect `git pull` to set my folder to the current version that git pulls from the repository. This though is not the case.

I also tried to `git reset --hard HEAD`, but this also does not delete the certain folders not belonging to the HEAD version.

On Ubuntu Linux this works as expected. When using `git pull` all the new folders are added and old ones are removed, so that after the pull the local version matches the repository's version.

Is there a special command for that in macOS's git? Is there a special reason for this behavior on macOS's git?

**EDIT 1:**

Entering `git clean -Xn` returns:

```
Would remove backend/.classpath
Would remove backend/.project
Would remove backend/src/.DS_Store
Would remove backend/src/main/.DS_Store
```

Comment: Are there any contents of the not-deleted directories ignored by git? (You can check by calling `git clean -Xn`)

Comment: @SimonDoppler Updated the above post.

Comment: @SimonDoppler No, the non deleted directory is called `administration2` and it is not listed within the `.gitignore`. I would have expected it to be deleted by git when using git pull, but it is still there and it contains `node_modules` whith contents of more than 600MB.